# Yolov4 for Non Image Data (sequence data)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, object-detection, yolo, yolov4

New to NN's. I know you can use sequence data in CNN's, but is it possible to pass sequence data into YOLO?

A sample input image has shape (height, width, depth) but a sample sequence (in TF/Keras) has shape (timesteps, features). Would reshaping the sequence to (x, y, z) work? How can this be done? As I see it, the depth of an image = 3 while the features of a sequence can often exceed 3.

Comment: YOLO is an object detector for images, it does not make much sense to use it on non-image data, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to identify recurring patterns in sequence data. 

Why didn't I just use a regular CNN or RNN? In a sequence, these recurring patterns could occur any x times. I don't see how I can possibly define an output layer to account for this (unless I find the max value for x and zero pad the y vector). For example: if x = 4, and a sample sequence only has 1 pattern, the y would be [1 0 0 0].

From my understanding, you can give object detection algorithms like YOLO labelled images that have varying x number of bounding boxes.

Comment: Most object detectors are also CNNs, so a CNN can also output a variable number of objects, same as an object detector works.

Comment: Interesting, how would I go about doing that? Say I have images that could contain 0 to 5 objects, each object has 4 coordinates as data points.